# is this safe? (qt QQueue.dequeue() c++ inline pointer dereference)

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, queue

```
Object object = *(queue.dequeue());
```

queue is a QQueue<Object*>. i'm concerned that the dequeued pointer is deleted before i dereference it. of course i can access `object`'s data but that doesn't mean anything. doing it all in one line like this is convenient (i don't want a pointer because i want `object` to be deleted automatically when it goes out of scope) but if it's not safe then i can't do it. please advise. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't immediately *unsafe* per se, but chances are you'll be *using it wrong*.

All your code does is make a **copy** of the element pointed to by the last element of `queue`. By dequeuing the element, you lose the pointer to it, and you now have no way of freeing that original object in case it was dynamically constructed.

**Correct example** (no dynamic objects, no leak):

```
QQueue<Foo*> q;

{
  Foo a;
  q.enqueue(&a);
  Foo b = *q.dequeue();
}
```

**Broken example** (dynamic object leaked):

```
QQueue<Foo*> q;
q.enqueue(new Foo);   // eeew, naked "new" in C++...
Foo c = *q.dequeue();
// now the newed element is leaked
```

You're right that `c` is safely destroyed at the end of its scope, but you're leaking the orginal, new'ed object, to which you have no pointer or reference now.

Comment: big thanks for the clarification. had no idea there was a copy implicit in a pointer to object dereference operation in c++. i think my confusion stems from working in perl for years prior.